# Can I get a login user Email using Android Facebook Graph-API

Tags: android, facebook, api, email, sdk

I want to get a email of facebook login User but I am not success still to now. 
Can anybody help me that it is possible using a Facebook_Android API or not?
explain with code if answer yes.

Comment: Put `email` in the permission, `facebook.request("me");` will return User detail in format of Json(typically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this post for getting Email of the User :

```
String response=ZValues.authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
useremail=obj.getString("email");
```

Util class will be available in Facebook code by default.

Comment: It was return a email like this "app+7kttso9kl9.iiu166.6d41dde7b0578912cb92813db0116297@proxymail.facebook.com" how can I get email in a proper format.

Comment: @Niraj That email tag will returns your email as it found in Facebook..May be check after some time..