# How to allow user to login via Facebook and Post Something in FeedBack Form Android Device

Tags: android, facebook

In my application I have a feedback form. The user has to first login via his/her facebook account and if the login is successful then the user can post some feedback in my feedback form.

So for that is there any API or library available? If any one has done this before than please help me on it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Predefined text directly posted on facebook wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271646/predefined-text-directly-posted-on-facebook-wall)

Comment: @down Voter what's wrong with this question?remember next time to give reason for downvoting else don't give answer to any one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below link of my SO answer for solve this issue, it may help you.

[Facebook Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271646/predefined-text-directly-posted-on-facebook-wall/11271730#11271730)

Comment: sorry i did not make it negative may be some one else dude

Comment: ok this is not an issue, please check it and if u have any issue then tell me.

Comment: ya thanks i got idea how can i do it inplace of posting something i justneed to post that to my feed back layout thanks i am trying as per that logic..

Comment: do u know how to fetch user information while we login via fb?

Comment: I don't know but you can see this link's documentation to solve that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: i solved query from this answer it's simple one i got all data in json respnse here is a link from where i got solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835262/can-i-get-a-login-user-email-using-android-facebook-graph-api/7835357#7835357